# MultiOS "Jet Database" for C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, database, qt, embedded-database

Hopefully I can articulate this well: I'm porting an application I made years ago from VB6 (I know, I know!) to C++/Qt. In my original application, one thing I liked was that I didn't need an actual SQL server running, I could just use MS Access .mdb files. I was wondering if something similar exists for Qt that will work on multiple OSes - a database stored in a file, pretty much, but that I can still run SQL queries with. Not sure if something like this exists or not, but any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, as the example Qt comes with SQLite support. Also I have deal with DBF files on Qt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I second the comment by "Mosg". Have a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: Agree. What OP needs is SQLite. Just change application's behavior to database types and everything will works

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/sql-driver.html) is the full list.